# query sql to use with python

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

What's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT ps_stock_available.quantity 
FROM ps_stock_available 
INNER JOIN ps_product_attribute ON ps_product_attribute.id_product ON ps_stock_available.id_product 
WHERE ps_product_attribute.reference =100102
```

Comment: Two `on` clauses don't normally follow each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT sa.quantity
FROM ps_stock_available sa INNER JOIN
     ps_product_attribute pa 
     ON sa.id_product = pa.id_product
WHERE pa.reference = 100102;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `ON` clause contains a boolean expression.
- A single `JOIN` has a single `ON` clause.